# QGIS Add geometry to attribute table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I am importing my data into QGIS from a local postgreSQL server. The dataset loaded into the database contains 11 columns including a X and Y column which are in the CRS (Coodinate Reference System): EPSG:21781, CH1903 / LV03. I am trying to plot these points as a layer in QGIS but when I import it using the “Add PostGIS layer” I have to click “Also list tables with no geometry” to find it. Once added it appears as an attribute table which I can go into the layer properties and select the correct CRS but it still doesn't appear correctly.

[image: QGIS layer properties]

I am still new to QGIS and PostgreSQL, am I doing something wrong or do I need to define the coordinates in the database before I import them to QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the geometry on the table. As of now, you are just displaying a table that does not contain any point so the coordinate system does not even apply.

So, first you would create the geometry column via PostGIS [AddGeometryColumn](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html)

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('myschema','mytable','geom',21781,'POINT',2);
```

Then you would update this new column with existing values.

```
UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SETSRID(ST_MakePoint(X, Y), 21781);
```

Comment: I have managed to create the column and when I try to update with the data from my X and Y columns I get this error:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeU9H.png

Comment: Make sure the schema where Postgis is installed is in your Search Path (typically public)

Comment: The schema is in the public domain (see image), is it how I am using the ST_SRID function perhaps?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQLcQ.png

Comment: Sorry typo, try with ST_SETSRID